# Object is not subscriptable

Tags: python

I'm having a bit of trouble with some python code (simple stuff).
It's getting to the point where I'm hoping that if I click run enough times it might work...

Here's the code:

```
Data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
Frequency = [1, 2, 3, 3, 1]

def mode(data1, frequency1):
    mode = [0]
    count = 0
    while count != len(frequency1):
        if frequency1[count] > mode[0]:
            mode = data1[count]
        elif frequency1[count] == mode:
           mode = [mode, data1[count]]
        count +=1
    return mode

mode = mode(Data, Frequency)
print(mode)
```

It returns :

```
 if Frequency[0] > mode[0]:

 TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

I had a look at another question & answer but it looked beyond me.
Where am I going wrong!

Edit: I know there are modules you can import to find the mean but I want to do it without importing anything.

Edit: entire code now posted. If I Don't make the mode variable a list it's fine until there are two modes.

Comment: Right... `mode` is an `int`... not some list... don't reuse variable names for different purposes, declare a different variable with a different name for each use.

Comment: I don't understand what your code is trying to do. What do you expect `mode[0]` to be in the first place that you need to convert it to an integer? Why are you storing the previous mode and the new one together in a list as `mode`?

Comment: As a side note, any loop of the form `count = 0`, `while count != len(frequency1):` `frequency1[count]` can (and should) be replaced by `for frequency in frequency1:`. If you need `count` for some reason, use `for count, frequency in enumerate(frequency1):`. But if you only need `count` to index another list in lockstep, don't do that; just do `for frequency, data in zip(frequency1, data1):`. However you do it, getting rid of the manual loop counter management eliminates a lot of easy-to-make potential bugs.

Comment: You also have a function named `mode` and a variable named `mode`.  When is which one which?  (The language has a strict definition, but this is a crazy way to write code.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check out your `int(mode[0])`.  You are basically saying, get the 0th element of... zero.  Perhaps you just want to lose the subscript?  Or change the type of mode?